# How can I support the 'placeholder' attribute in IE 8-9 with Mootools?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, mootools, placeholder

Other people have asked this, but the answers are all for jQuery.

Comment: http://mootools.net/forge/browse?search=placeholder and https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-GB&hl=en&q=mootools+placeholder - plenty to choose from. if you want mootools answers then look for that?

Comment: Why was this question voted down? It's a perfectly good question!

Answer (score 5):

First, you should use the Mootools plugin 'OverText' http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/OverText which basically simulates this functionality. It will actually work in any browser so, you can use it and forget about the placeholder attribute altogether if you want to. But if you want to support placeholder when available but use OverText for older browsers, you can do it this way:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    // create a test element
    var test = new Element('input'); 
    // if it has 'placeholder' this browser supports it already so you can exit
    if(("placeholder" in test)) { return; } 
    // for older browsers, get all the inputs which you have assigned a 'placeholder' attribute to
    $$('input[placeholder]').each(function(el) { 
        // and create an overtext for them using the value of the placeholder attribute
        new OverText(el, { textOverride: el.get('placeholder') });
    });
});
```

Comment: you should always use native functionality and include JS or other backups, your site will run faster, have better usability over all

Comment: Why is this voted down? This is using native functionality when available and falling back on JS for older browsers. This is the way to do it.

Comment: Ha! Another down vote? This is BS. I assure you, this is ***THE WAY*** to do this thing which you want to do.

Answer (score -2):

```
/**
 * IE doesn't support the placeholder attribute, but we can set the value attribute.
 */
if (Browser.Engines.trident()) {
  var elements = $$('input[placeholder]');
  elements.map(function(it) {
    if (!it.getAttribute('value')) {
      it.setAttribute('value', it.getAttribute('placeholder'));
      it.onfocus = function() {
        it.setAttribute('value', '');
        it.onfocus = null;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: this is quite flat and will fail in way too many cases, it's also not written very well from a mootools standpoint.

Comment: First of all, this seems to be for an old version of Mootools. Second, `Browser.Engines.trident()` has never been anything. I think you meant `Browser.Engine.trident` but that's still a terrible way to test for this. You need to test for the feature, not the browser.